# Bash script and whitespaces in file names

Tags: bash, macos

I’m having a problem with filenames having whitespace in a bash script on Mac OSX:

```
name="My File" #file name
version="1.0.0"

echo "Copying AAX..."
mkdir aax/
cp -R "/Library/Application Support/Avid/Audio/Plug-Ins/""${name}".aaxplugin aax

echo "Copying AU..."
mkdir au/
cp -R "~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/""${name}".component au

echo "Copying VST2..."
mkdir vst/
cp -R "~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/""${name}".vst vst
```

It goes perfectly fine with the AAX file, but it won’t find the file for AU and VST. I tried quoting different parts of the command lines, but I always get “no such file or directory” for those two.

What’s wrong there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Tilde (`~`) does not expand in quotes; use `$HOME` instead if you want to use it that way.
2. If you want to use tilde then only `${name}` should be double-quoted (to prevent word-splitting).

So that would look like this (`1`):

```
"$HOME/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/${name}".component au
```

Or like this (`2`):

```
~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/"${name}".component au
```

Comment: Aren't the curly braces redundant with double quotes ?

Comment: @Httqm: it would still need to be double-quoted; often curly brackets are used for better readability.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that the tilde wouldn't expand while quoted. Now it works as expected.